# Show properties vertically on report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset with following data:

```
ID
prop1
prop2
prop3
prop4
```

I want to show the data in a table like that

```
--------------------------
ID       |  ID_VALUE
--------------------------
prop1    |  prop1_VALUE
--------------------------
prop2    |  prop2_VALUE
--------------------------
prop3    |  prop3_VALUE
--------------------------
prop4    |  prop4_VALUE
--------------------------
--------------------------
ID       |  ID_VALUE
--------------------------
prop1    |  prop1_VALUE
--------------------------
prop2    |  prop2_VALUE
--------------------------
prop3    |  prop3_VALUE
--------------------------
prop4    |  prop4_VALUE
--------------------------
```

I'm doing a column grouping by ID but data is written horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reporting services you can use [List](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121(v=sql.100).aspx) control to display data in a free-form layout.

Comment: Thank you! It's what I needed